# HttpWebRequest: How to remove the last slash from the URI

Tags: c#, rest, httpwebrequest

I am working on a client to a given service. I cannot do anything on the server due it is not in my domain.
The server is responding in this URL:

"http://nameoftheserver.com/ITSM/UserAuthorizationService"

And, when I instantiate the request:

```
var endpoint = "...nameoftheserver.com/ITSM/";

var parameters = "UserAuthorizationService";

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("{0}{1}", endPoint , parameters));
```

Tthe fact is that the `request.Address` has the value

```
.../ITSM/UserAuthorizationService/
```

and the service's response is a `404` because of the last slash.

Anyone knows how to delete this slash from the request.Address?

Thank you very much

Comment: It is strange. I copied and tried your code and my `request.Address` does not have the ending slash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this really answers your question, but could you use the String.TrimEnd to remove the slash?

[String.TrimEnd Method (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TrimEnd method like this:

```
(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
    string.Format("{0}{1}", endPoint , parameters).TrimEnd('/')
);
```